# c# how to return a string from a client to a server in TCP and UDP

Tags: c#, server, tcp, udp, client

So in my client I am looking for a way to return how many times a background worker was run to a server. Here is the code section for the client:

```
}
    public int searchcount = 1;
    public void SL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();


            tcpclnt.Connect(RecieveIP.Text, 8001); // use the ipaddress as in the server program

            MessageBox.Show("Connected");




            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();





            MessageBox.Show("Listening for information......");


            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);
            string atk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bb.AsSpan(0, k));
            Console.WriteLine($"S Connected to attack server at IPv4 address {RecieveIP.Text} Attack command Received: {atk}. If command is g, attacking google. Y means attacking yahoo. A means attacking aol. Yo meants attacking youtube, and s is attacking spotify");//test

            //if you want your check
            //this will not work if your incoming data contains white space or other bytes that were converted.

            if (atk == "g" || atk.Contains("g"))

                MessageBox.Show("Recieved Command " + atk);

            if (atk == "g")
            {


                MessageBox.Show("Google");
               search.RunWorkerAsync();
```

On thought, I do have a string

```
public int searchcount = 1;
```

Which the background worker in question adds one to display to the person running the client how many times it was run.

```
Console.WriteLine("Since start: " + count++.ToString());
```

Is there a way to return the count++ string to the server via both TCP and UDP? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TCP(socket) is a protocol that you can send packages both ways. Udp on the other hand is stateless, you can only send packages from client to server. You cant maintain UDP connections open and keep sending/receiving packages. That said, you can send packages from client to server using UDP if the server dont need to respond your package.

I'm really doing some resume on what tcp/udp protocols are and i really encourage you to read about them on MS official docs before using anything on production.

Here some TCP , UDP and  sockets examples and documentation on MS official docs.

[Tcp Client/Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-tcp-services.)

[Udp Client/Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-udp-services)

[Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-client-socket-example)